# Ratio distribution of standard normal distribution and exponential distribution

Tags: probability, statistics

Let X = N(0,1) and Y = Exp(λ), derive the pdf of Z = X/Y, given that X and Y are independent.

[This is the entire question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CG29l.png)

I've tried to use convolution (using the CDF and differentiating it)

[I obtain this integral](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BvRww.png) but I don't know what to do with it, I've tinkered around with substitution but it won't equate to an identity.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: Never omit independence assumptions. Not all r.v.'s are independent.

Answer (score 0):

Here a sketch of a possible calculation of the integral you obtained (but please rewrite it using MathJax).

You can start by rewriting the integral as:

$I=-\frac{\lambda}{z^2}\int_0^{+\infty}dy e^{-(y^2z^2/2+\lambda y)}[(-yz^2-\lambda)+\lambda]$

The first addend now should be trivial. The second one reads:

$I_2=-\frac{\lambda^2}{z^2}\int_0^{+\infty}dy e^{-(y^2z^2/2+\lambda y)}$

And for this complete first the square:

$y^2z^2/2+\lambda y=(yz/\sqrt{2}+\lambda/(\sqrt{2}z))^2-\lambda^2/2z^2$

This suggest the subsitution:

$yz/\sqrt{2}+\lambda/(\sqrt{2}z)=y'$

after this, $I_2$ should provide an error function.

At the end, it is always better to check with some software:

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Integrate+from+0+to+infty+exp%28-%28%28x%5E2a%5E2%29%2F2%2Bbx%29%29*x